# Prevent EntityFramework from returning escaped quote for json string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

I'm returning a string via entity framework within a .cshtml file.
The code looks like this:

```
var mapGeoJson = JSON.parse(@Model.RouteMapJSON);
```

When it shows up in the browser it has the quotes in the json escaped like this:

```
JSON.parse({&quot;type&quot;: &quot;FeatureCollection&quot;, . . .
```

But I need it to be the real quotes and not the escaped values.

How do I prevent EF from escaping the quotes?

Here is my EF code first definition for the field:

```
 [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
 public string RouteMapJSON { get; set; }
```

I've also tried replacing the quotes (both in C# and JS) after they are returned and that's not working either.

Comment: I'm saving map Geo JSON as well.  Guess I didn't run across this issue since I'm doing an AJAX POST from Javascript instead of from one of my MVC Views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor is doing that, not EF. Try using `@Html.Raw()`:

```
var mapGeoJson = @Html.Raw(Model.RouteMapJSON);
```

Comment: I think you're missing the JSON.parse call from the original.

Comment: @emodendroket Based on my experience doing this and on his output above, the javascript parse shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Entity Framework doing that.  To get unescaped text in the view you have to use an MvcHtmlString.

```
var mapGeoJson = JSON.parse(@(new MvcHtmlString(Model.RouteMapJSON));
```

That should give the results you want.